# URLSession issue

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlsession, xcode8

I'm converting my project to Swift 3.

I have this code in Swift 2.2 :

```
lazy var downloadsSession: NSURLSession = {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("bgSessionConfiguration")
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    return session
}()
```

And the code is converted to Swift 3:

```
lazy var downloadsSession: URLSession = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "bgSessionConfiguration")
    let session = URLSession(session: configuration, downloadTask: self, didFinishDownloadingToURL: nil)

    return session
}()
```

But such error is:

> "cannot convert value of type URLSessionConfiguration to expected argument type URLSession"

`URLSession` have not any method to get `URLSessionConfiguration`!

Update:
Here is picture of swift3 auto correction when used of this function:

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

[image]

How do I fix this code?

Comment: This is a strange one, usually the compiler would give a more useful error but I assume that you are implementing URLSessionDownloadDelegate and it is getting confused with this function `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
   downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate/1411575-urlsession

Comment: I had a similar problem with **URLSession**, old delegate methods of URLSessionDelegate starts like this `URLSession(session: ...` etc and the compiler is trying to call a method not a constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initializer you are looking for `URLSession` is like `init(configuration:delegate:delegateQueue:)`. So change your initialization of session like this.

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Comment: Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'configuration:delegate:delegateQueue:', expected 'session:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:')

Comment: @MohammadHossein I am sure you are missing something, try to clean build your project, the answer is correct you can  check it here at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init)

Comment: @MohammadHossein Sorry for late response, But you can check here https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcCCc.png it is completely working for me with successful build

Comment: The problem was that I did not rename urlSession function for swift3!
`func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)`

thank you very much !

Comment: Sir I used Alamofire manually by adding source file I am getting same error in SessionManager.swift file saying **Cannot convert value of type 'URLSessionConfiguration' to expected argument type 'URLSession'**, 
Error is in this line `self.session = URLSession(configurationn, didReceiveChallenge: delegate, completionHandler: nil)`
Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are implementing URLSessionDownloadDelegate method and compiler is getting confused with this function. Check it out!